# Dynamic pre-fetching data in nextJS

Tags: api, next.js

I am trying to pre-fetch data for my project in nextJS. It is a dynamic page that grabs the users ID and redirects them to their profile (url example: profile/0xab83). I am trying to use getServerSideProps, but it returns an empty object. The data I am fetching is from a sanity database. How can i fix this? I do not need the ID to fetch the data at all, but also I am unable to make this a static route.

Code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const query = `*[_type == "marketItems"]  {
    contractAddress,
  }`;

  const data = await client.fetch(query);
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

function profile(data) {
  console.log(data)
  return(<></>)
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error when fetching the data inside `getServerSideProps`? Check the terminal where you started the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function profile({data}) {
  console.log(data)
  return(<></>)
}
```